# CGAL error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013, lnk2019, cgal

I am building CGAL 4.6 32 bit with Boost 1.58.0 32bit ... the generation is done without error using cmake gui 3.2.2

But when I am trying to build it with visual studio 2013 I am getting the following error:

```
all_files.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)

>all_files.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)

>all_files.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const *,class boost::shared_ptr<struct boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>,void *,bool)" (?set_tss_data@detail@boost@@YAXPEBXV?$shared_ptr@Utss_cleanup_function@detail@boost@@@2@PEAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread_specific_ptr<int>::~thread_specific_ptr<int>(void)" (??1?$thread_specific_ptr@H@boost@@QEAA@XZ)

>C:\Program Files\CGAL-4.6\bin\Release\CGAL-vc120-mt-4.6.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Can anyone help? [btw its trying to build the solution for `x64` and if I change it to `wix32` its skipping the build.]

Comment: You say that you are building CGAL for x64, but at the same time you have a 32 bits version of Boost. Is not it the simple reason for the error?

Comment: I am building both CGAL & Boost for 32 bit. But when I am building it in VS 2013 its by default taking the 64 bit build. I then checked the cmake script and changed it to 32 bit build. 

Now everthing is 32 bit but still the eror exists.

Comment: I suggest that you, in CMake, you set the variable `Boost_DEBUG` to `TRUE`/`ON`, and re-configure. During the configuration run, there will be several lines about Boost libraries. Please edit your question to add a copy-paste of those lines. That will give us a lot more information.